# How to make Python accessible via CMD prompt without full path?

Tags: python, windows

I have Python installed on D:\python27. Now I want to kno how to make it so that I don't have to type

```
D:\python27\python.exe myscript.py
```

but instead, just use

```
python myscript.py
```

I know that this should already be configured after the install but somehow, the laptop I'm using didn't register the python shortcut. So how do I set it manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the start menu on win7:

1. right-click on "computer".
2. Select "Properties"
3. click "Advanced System Settings"
4. click "Environment Variables"
5. Under the "System Variables" sub-section select the Variable `Path` and click "Edit".
6. Append ";C:\Python27" to the existing path, click ok, ok.
7. Restart any console you have open for the new path setting to take effect, and try typing "python" to start a python session, it should start for you.

Comment: very strange.  Do you have more than one installation of python?  If you remove the added python path, open a new console, and type "python" what error do you get?

Comment: Well I'm not entirely sure about that myself. This is a company laptop and IDK if the previous owner had python installed. I couldn't see it on the default install location so I decided to do an install myself. In fact, this was the very error I got which was why I asked how to set the path manually.

Comment: If you still see the same error after removing the path and restarting the console, there should be another path in the PATH variable that points to a python installation, try finding and removing that first.

Comment: Okay, I got it to work finally. I while the crash screen is visible, i opened up Process Explorer and saw from there where the python.exe is located. It was on system32. I tried renaming that to python_.exe and re-added the path, it's now running as it should. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

On command line:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;d:\python27
```

To persist over reboot, update your environment variable through, system->properties.